# filter takes one calls but it didn't takes time

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, filter

I am checking the performance of filter with map using cProfile,

```
cProfile.run("""
s = [range(10000) for i in range(10000)]
filter(None, map(lambda x:x[0], s))""")
         20005 function calls in 42.272 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    2.467    2.467   42.272   42.272 <string>:2(<module>)
    10000    0.004    0.000    0.004    0.000 <string>:3(<lambda>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {filter}
        1    0.201    0.201    0.205    0.205 {map}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
    10001   39.599    0.004   39.599    0.004 {range}
```

From the above analysis I have observed filter and it calls one time but it didn't takes time, Why it didn't takes time ?

Comment: filter works differently on Python2 and Python3, so which are you running this on?

Comment: @gnibbler I have used python2.7

Answer (score 0):

If there is a function call, there will be some time consumption to call that function.

That time migth be very minute, which is lesser than the millisecond.

In your Cprofile Test , the maximum unit of time can be represented is 1 millisecond.

If a function takes less than 1 milli second, Cprofile shows it as 0 milliseconds.

That means here filter takes less millisecond, I found this by testing your code in following way.

```
import datetime

l= [range(4) for i in range(4)]
a = datetime.datetime.now()
filter(None, l)
b = datetime.datetime.now()
c = b - a
print c.seconds
print c.microseconds

Output on my system

0
35
```